# Page specific javascript... better to go inline or have it in the main Javascript definition?

Tags: javascript

For javascript functions that only apply to one page, in a large(ish) web app - is it better to have the scripts inline or in the main javascript file?

Comment: Is it a 50,000 long piece of code? Do you have tens of thousands/hundreds of thousands of requests per minute/hour/day? If not, who cares?

Comment: Fairly small - there's about 8 pages with page-specific functions.  All of the inline functions are about 10-40 lines.

Comment: Pretty much the same question that was posted and answered here: [embedded vs linked JS / CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658390/embedded-vs-linked-js-css)

Comment: I tend to put them inline, or in a separate script file but include it server-side. There's an argument you could keep it all in external javascript for performance reasons, but it often gets difficult to maintain this way

Comment: The main javascript definition is 1000 line (before minimized).

Comment: You're optimizing without any reason to if it's as you describe. `:s` In your situation, *make it easy on yourself*. Optimize when you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application gets little traffic, use whatever you like best.

If your application gets a huge amount of traffic, you want to minimize:

1. the number of distinct requestable resources in your application to maximize cacheability
2. the size of each individual resource to optimize the empty cache experience.

1 and 2 contradict each other, so you have to pick a tradeoff appropriate to your application.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer having a proper [module](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2010/03/29/understanding-dojo-require/) [system](http://requirejs.org/) and useful [compilation tools](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/build/) so I don't need to have to worry sacrificing efficiency when it comes to keeping my code organized.

Comment: That's a lot of work for some kind's of requirements (but good advice, nonetheless).

Comment: Well, he said it was a large(ish) web app :P

Comment: Which (may) mean rearchitecting the JS include infrastructure could be laborious.

Comment: ...in which case he is in trouble either way :P

Comment: That depends. Just because someone *hasn't* done it a particular way doesn't mean it has to be FUBAR.